# how to check if a string contains any form of an apostrophe not just single quote and ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am using the following code to check if a string contains an apostrophe:

```
string.scan(/’|'/)
```

I have included two types of single quotation because I found that using just the standard ' did not catch some strings that contain an apostrophe using the ’

My concern is that if I am checking strings that may contain other fonts or styles my regex won't catch the apostrophe.

Is there a more general approach that would catch all forms of an apostrophe?

Comment: The first one is indeed an apostrophe, the other one is right single quotation mark. Anyway why don't you find all the possible variations and match them all? check this out: [Punctuation, Initial quote](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pi/list.htm) -
[Punctuation, Final quote](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pf/list.htm)

Comment: .An example string and your desired result would be helpful.

Comment: Fonts and styles are a matter of how the string is presented on the screen / paper. They are completely irrelevant to your question. An apostrophe character is an apostrophe character, no matter whether it is rendered in blue or green or italics or Comic Sans.

Comment: Thanks for the link Thrasher I will use it in combination with Maverick_Mrt's answer and Eric's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight single quote is the generic ver­ti­cal quo­ta­tion marks:

- straight sin­gle quote (`'`)

Curly quotes are the quo­ta­tion marks used in good ty­pog­ra­phy. There are two curly single quote char­ac­ters:

- the open­ing sin­gle quote (`‘`)
- the clos­ing sin­gle quote (`’`)

Going by the above three variants:

You maytry this:

```
string.scan(/['‘’]/)
```

Answer (score 2):

Those would probably be the most common ones :

```
/[‘’']/
```

If you just need to check if a string contains a regex, you shouldn't use [scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) :

```
"apostrophe's" =~ /[‘’']/ #=> 10
```

[`=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) will stop at the first match.

Comment: Thanks for your response Eric.  Question: I only want to determine if a string contains an apostrophe and your regex seems to contain double quotes. Wouldn't that match a string with double quotations then?

Comment: Yes it would. Updated